# How to convert milliseconds into a readable date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following:

```
new Date(1324339200000).toUTCString()
```

Outputs:

```
"Tue, 20 Dec 2011 00:00:00 GMT"
```

I need it to return `Dec 20`. Is there a better method I can use besides `toUTCString()`? I am looking for any way to parse through milliseconds, to return a human readable date.

Comment: It *did* return a human-readable date. Do you just want to know how to [format the date in certain ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/901048).

Comment: @mblase75, yeap, that's right

Comment: The moment.js library can also be used http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using the library Datejs you can accomplish this quite elegantly, with its `toString` [format specifiers](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers): http://jsfiddle.net/TeRnM/1/.

```
var date = new Date(1324339200000);

date.toString("MMM dd"); // "Dec 20"
```

Comment: Datejs at http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/list was last updated on 2007? Is this the same library you are suggesting?

Comment: @Christian Fazzini: Yes, it's a bit old (http://www.datejs.com/ also states this). It still works fine though :)

Comment: @pimvdb your fiddle outputs it like this 
Tue Dec 20 2011 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and I want only Tue Dec 20 2011 05:30:00

Comment: I think the words "Using the library Datejs" **should be** emphasized!

Answer (score 50):

You can use datejs and convert in different formate. I have tested some formate and working fine.

```
var d = new Date(1469433907836); // Parameter should be long value

d.toLocaleString()     // 7/25/2016, 1:35:07 PM
d.toLocaleDateString() // 7/25/2016
d.toDateString()       // Mon Jul 25 2016
d.toTimeString()       // 13:35:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
d.toLocaleTimeString() // 1:35:07 PM
d.toISOString();       // 2016-07-25T08:05:07.836Z
d.toJSON();            // 2016-07-25T08:05:07.836Z
d.toString();          // Mon Jul 25 2016 13:35:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
d.toUTCString();       // Mon, 25 Jul 2016 08:05:07 GMT
```

Comment: Make sure to pass an integer as the parameter of Date, if you pass a string it will say invalid data.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/yc7q4owa/4/ for working example of this

Answer (score 18):

No, you'll need to do it manually.

```js
function prettyDate(date) {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' + date.getUTCFullYear();
}

console.log(prettyDate(new Date(1324339200000)));
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a solution. Later you can split by ":" and take the values of the array

```
 /**
 * Converts milliseconds to human readeable language separated by ":"
 * Example: 190980000 --> 2:05:3 --> 2days 5hours 3min
 */
function dhm(t){
    var cd = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ch = 60 * 60 * 1000,
        d = Math.floor(t / cd),
        h = '0' + Math.floor( (t - d * cd) / ch),
        m = '0' + Math.round( (t - d * cd - h * ch) / 60000);
    return [d, h.substr(-2), m.substr(-2)].join(':');
}

//Example
var delay = 190980000;                   
var fullTime = dhm(delay);
console.log(fullTime);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with just a few lines of pure js codes.

```
var date = new Date(1324339200000);
    var dateToStr = date.toUTCString().split(' ');
    var cleanDate = dateToStr[2] + ' ' + dateToStr[1] ;
console.log(cleanDate);
```

returns Dec 20.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I  just tested this and it works fine

```
var d = new Date(1441121836000);
```

The data object has a constructor which takes milliseconds as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [`lonesomeday`'s example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579919/1873386) (upvote that answer not this one), I ran into this output:

> `undefined NaN, NaN`

```js
var datetime = '1324339200000'; //LOOK HERE

function prettyDate(date) {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' + date.getUTCFullYear();
}

console.log(prettyDate(new Date(datetime))); //AND HERE
```

The cause was using a string as input. To fix it, prefix the string with a plus sign:

> `prettyDate(new Date(+datetime));`

```js
var datetime = '1324339200000';

function prettyDate(date) {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' + date.getUTCFullYear();
}

console.log(prettyDate(new Date(+datetime))); //HERE
```

To add Hours/Minutes to the output:

```js
var datetime = '1485010730253';

function prettyDate(date) {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  return months[date.getUTCMonth()] +' '+ date.getUTCDate()+ ', '+ date.getUTCHours() +':'+ date.getUTCMinutes();
}

console.log(prettyDate(new Date(+datetime)));
```