# convert date in milliseconds to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery table with a column containing  dates in milliseconds format. I would like to convert from milliseconds to mm/dd/yyyy. I haven't been able to figure out how to convert the date value and integrate it into my script.

Please check out my fiddle and offer any advice you may have: http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/eLbq2wvh/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.corsproxy.com/dvl.thomascooper.com/data/json_return.json", function(data) {
        //static table head
        $('table.stats').append("<th>" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Date" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Brand" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Author" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Title" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Posts" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Exposure" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "Engagement" + "</th>");
        //loop through json data
        $.each(data.data.rows, function(i, val) {
            //+1 to number each row starting at 1
            var rowNum = i + 1;
            //create table rows and cell and populate with data 
            $('table.stats').append("<tr>" + "<td>" + rowNum + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[0].value + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[1].value + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[2] + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[3].label + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[4].values[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[5].values[0] + "</td>" + "<td>" + val[6].values[0] + "</td>" + "</tr>");

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/eLbq2wvh/

Comment: You can use: var date = new Date(val in msec); as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579861/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-a-readable-date

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
new Date(val[0].value).toLocaleFormat('%m/%d/%Y')
```

instead of `val[0].value` .

Refer to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).

Comment: "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."