# How to convert timestamp to readable date/time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have an API [result](https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?) giving out timestamp like this `1447804800000`. How do I convert this to a readable format using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: var x = new Date(1447804800000); Returns: Wed Nov 18 2015 11:00:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds into a readable date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579861/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-a-readable-date)

Comment: did you get the expected output?

Comment: @KunalGadhia - Yeah now it works great. Thanks for sharing that function :)

Comment: @KunalGadhia - Do you also know how to do it backwards? Like, given Wed Nov 18 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and covert it to 1447804800000 ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can convert this to a readable date using `new Date()` method

if you have a specific date stamp, you can get the corresponding date time format by the following method

```
var date = new Date(timeStamp);
```

in your case

```
var date = new Date(1447804800000);
```

this will return

```
Wed Nov 18 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: Do you also know how to do it backwards? Like, given Wed Nov 18 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and covert it to 1447804800000 ??

Comment: Javascript does not provides any inbuilt method for reverse conversion of date to date time stamp. We may need to write a custom method for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Call This function and pass your date :

JS :

```
function getDateFormat(date) {
var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

if (month.length < 2)
    month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2)
    day = '0' + day;
var date = new Date();
date.toLocaleDateString();

return [day, month, year].join('-');
}
;
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the REST API returned timestamp with decimal. Below code snippet example worked for me.

```
var ts= 1551246342.000100; // say this is the format for decimal timestamp.
var dt = new Date(ts * 1000);
alert(dt.toLocaleString()); // 2/27/2019, 12:45:42 AM this for displayed
```